# RxJava2 get event when Observable/Completed is completed or disposed

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I need to show a progress dialog when I subscribe to a `Completable` and hide it after the operation is completed(successfully or with an error) or is canceled.

So I do

```
final Completable completable = notificationRepository.markAllAsRead()
        .doOnSubscribe(d -> progressDialog.show())
        .doOnError(error -> progressDialog.dismiss())
        .doOnComplete(() -> progressDialog.dismiss())
        .doOnDispose(() -> progressDialog.dismiss());
```

Is there any elegant way to get single callback when 
`onError`, `onComplete` or `onDispose` happens?

Comment: See `doFinally`.

Comment: Thank you, very match! I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have done some tests, so

`doOnDispose` is called when the subscriber cancels the subscription, it is never called after completion.

`doOnComplete` is called when the `Observable`/`Completable` completes successfully. (Error doesn't happen)

`doOnError` is called when `Observable`/`Completable` emits an error. (`OnComplete` is not called).

`doOnTerminate` is called when `Observable`/`Completable` emits an `error` or `completes`. So it's `doOnComplete` + `doOnError`

`doFinally` is called when `Completable`/`Observable` signals `onError` or `onComplete` or gets disposed. So it is `doOnDispose` + `doOnError` +`doOnComplete`.

So `doFinally` is what I was looking for, Thank you akarnokd for help.