# Conflicting answers over result of .isDisposed()

Tags: observable, rx-java2

I'm sure I read somewhere that `.isDisposed()` is not guaranteed to return `true` unless `.dispose()` has been explicitly called. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45589930/does-rxjava2-auto-dispose-observable-when-they-call-completed-or-error) says that it *always* returns `true` after `.onComplete()` has been called, while [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118182/rxjava2-get-event-when-observable-completed-is-completed-or-disposed) says that `.doOnDispose()` is *never* called after a completion event.

I'd like to create an `Action` that runs if the `Observable` is disposed, but not if it completes normally. Is there any way to guarantee this? What is the official answer on the semantics of `.isDisposed()`? The possibility that it might or might not return `true` after completion isn't very satisfactory.

Update: I'm trying to convert a `Single` into a 1-item `Observable`. Once it emits its item, it will of course become completed. But I would still like its `.dispose()` method to trigger a separate action:

```
        mObservable = mSingle
                .toObservable()
                .doOnDispose( () -> {
                    do stuff} );
```

The whole reason I am converting the `Single` to an `Observable` is to have the ability to handle the `doOnDispose()` action. Am I correct that a `Single` is torn down after emitting its item, so therefore its `doOnDispose` method is no longer available? (If I'm wrong about this I can skip the conversion to an `Observable`)

Comment: `doOnDispose` runs only when the sequence is disposed. The lambda- based `subscribe` methods return a `Disposable` that reports disposed upon termination.

Comment: And I presume that if I create my own `Observer` object I can handle this any way I choose?

Comment: What do you want to do? Call `Disposable.dispose()` from `Observer.onComplete()`?

Comment: I've edited the question to explain more fully

Comment: `doOnDispose` may not execute if the sequence has terminated, depending on what chain you have. Some operators disconnect themselves from the upstream so `dispose()` may not propagate beyond them after a terminal event. It makes no sense to run `doOnDispose` in that case as the operators themselves are responsible for cleanup. What is that you want to execute specifically upon dispose?

Comment: In this case I want to subscribe to a different `Single` (which queues an async call with `OkHttp3` and emits the response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@akarnokd has pointed out something I never fully understood: when you use lambdas in a `subscribe()` call, under the hood a `LambdaSubscriber` is created, and it reports `isDisposed() true` on termination.

If you don't want this, you must evidently write your own `Observer` with the desired behavior. AFAIK there is no way to swap out the default `LambdaSubscriber`.